# No such column error SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the next code to create my db..

```
public class ModeloPaciente extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//Tabla Proposicion Condicional
static final String proposicionCondicionalTabla="ProposicionCondicional";
static final String colproposicionCondicionalID="ProposicionCondicionalID";
static final String colproposicionCondicionalDescripcion="ProposicionCondicionalDescripcion";
static final String colproposicionCondicionalcuandoInferirForeign="CuandoInferir";

public ModeloPaciente(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {    

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+proposicionCondicionalTabla+" " +
"("+colproposicionCondicionalID+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
colproposicionCondicionalDescripcion+ " TEXT NOT NULL," +
colproposicionCondicionalcuandoInferirForeign+" INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
"FOREIGN KEY ("+colproposicionCondicionalcuandoInferirForeign+") REFERENCES    "+cuandoInferirTabla+"    
("+colcuandoInferirID+"));");             
}
```

Later I put data inside the table like this

```
public boolean insertarProposicion(Proposicion proposicion) {
    try {
           SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
           ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
           cv.put(colproposicionCondicionalDescripcion, proposicion.getProposicionCondicionalDescripcion());               
           cv.put(colproposicionCondicionalcuandoInferirForeign, getCuandoInferirID(proposicion.getProposicionCondicionalCuandoInferirForeign()));
           db.insert(proposicionCondicionalTabla, colproposicionCondicionalID, cv);
         //db.close();
           return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return false;
    }
```

But I get an error that said:

```
06-07 15:36:15.507: E/Database(257): Error inserting CuandoInferir=1 ProposicionCondicionalDescripcion=Se debe inferir acerca de los dias de marcha realizados o no
06-07 15:36:15.507: E/Database(257): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: CuandoInferir: , while compiling: INSERT INTO ProposicionCondicional(CuandoInferir, ProposicionCondicionalDescripcion) VALUES(?, ?);
```

And I check the database and it has the corresponding column "CuandoInferir"..¿What happen, I do not know? Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't post your title with all capitals. And do make it have something to do with the problem you are having. Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq You'll have much better luck getting help if you follow the guidelines in there.

Comment: The error message is right. Listen to it.

Comment: I see and see, and see.... the error message..maybe I saturated, but I can not see the error. Seriously

Answer (score 1):

You might be working with an older version of the database. Clear your app's data and try again:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> --> <kbd>Applications</kbd> --> <kbd>Manage applications</kbd> --> <kbd>[your app]</kbd> --> <kbd>Clear data</kbd>

Comment: Do you refer in Eclipse IDE or where Can I do this

Comment: You should do this on your device (or emulator, if that's what you are using). i.e. Go to the app launcher and press "settings", then "applications", etc.

Comment: I did this but it still does not work,  I finally deleted the column 'Cuando Inferir' and works fine, just god knows what happen ...I suppose. The bad part is that I broke my model...

Comment: Try and keep your variables to 10-12 characters at most... that's my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, however I would check the existing database. Check the column names in the 'ProposicionCondicional' table. You can do it by opening your database in sqlite3 following these steps (obviously connect your phone to pc before doing the steps)

```
adb shell
cd /data/data/<your.applications.package>/databases
sqlite3 <databases_name>
.schema
```

See if the table really has the 'CuandoInferir' column. If not, try to recreate the table.

Comment: I checked the db and the column effectively appears, and I turn crazy ..why it does not work. Also I cleaned the project in Eclipse and refreshed it and so on...

Comment: Alright, just a random idea - could you use a different encoding (i.e. different language) while creating the database, so the names just seems to be the same visually while being really different?

Another thing - may be you can try creating the database without the foreign key, just as a test, to see if it will work.

Comment: I finally deleted the column 'Cuando Inferir' and works fine, just god knows what happen ...I suppose. The bad part is that I broke my model...